# Why do "carnival" and "conference" lack the definite article?

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

...this seems common in British usage, at least.  Do these two kinds of noun have something in common? They are usually capitalised as proper nouns.

Examples of usage:

- "Stewarding at Conference is a rewarding and fun experience" ([source](http://www.labour.org.uk/pages/stewarding_annual_conference))
- "For one of the biggest black music events in the world, Carnival has been criminally overlooked by broadcasters" ([source](http://www.timeout.com/london/music/boiler-room-at-carnival-stream-if-you-wanna-go-harder))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're being used as proper nouns.

In the context of the first piece you quote, *Conference* is used as a name for Labour's Annual Conference.

In the context of the second piece you quote, *Carnival* is used as a name for the Notting Hill Carnival.

As proper nouns they don't need articles, though it normal to capitalise them.

Comment: I'm interested to see you wrote "*the* Notting Hill Carnival". We also say "*the* Declaration of Independence"; but when it comes to "Magna Carta" the definite article seems to be optional. Perhaps this needs another question...

Comment: @seb for one thing, "Magna Carta" is Latin and Latin has no articles, so one can translate it as "the great charter" (so "the Magna Carta" would make no sense) or as "great charter" (so "the Magna Carta" would be natural). That said, there is indeed further inconsistencies that goes on with articles in proper nouns.

Comment: It's interesting, though, isn't it, that in both cases we'd actually expand the shortened proper nouns with the definite article: "For one of the biggest black music events in the world, the Notting Hill Carnival has been criminally overlooked" and "Stewarding at the Labour Party Conference is a rewarding and fun experience".

Comment: @seb well the longer two come from noun phrases but can serve as proper nouns just by being definite (hence the definite article), "the Notting Hill Carnival" implies it refers to only one through that "the". "Notting Hill Carnival" implies it refers to only one through being used grammatically as a proper noun (as likewise does the use of "Carnival" this question was about).

Comment: "it normal" -> "it is normal"

Answer (score 3):

While Jon Hanna's answer is entirely correct, I would add that it seems a peculiarity of BrE (as opposed to the entirely sensible AmE(;)) to use this construction. "Doctor will see you now," and "She needs to be admitted to Hospital" are other examples.

Comment: I think "Doctor will see you now" comes from using "Doctor" as a form of address, from which proper noun use follows differently. "She needs to be admitted to Hospital" would not be the en-GB form, but rather "She needs to be admitted to hospital". Which is a proper noun form (though some object that it isn't a proper noun) also found in en-US where "that is history repeating itself" is found.

Comment: It's not peculiar to BrE - it's just the same as using "Congress" to refer to the United States Congress...

Comment: Agree with @jon about the hospital example, it's similar to "Jill took Mike to school", where no article is needed and doesn't seem to be the same kind of usage as we're seeing with Conference.